# Work required to form shell around point charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, work

How would you find the work required to form a shell of radius $R$ and of total charge $-q$ which is spread uniformly around a point charge $q$ at the origin by bringing in the charge $-q$ and spreading it across the shell? I attempted the following $$dW = d\bar{q}V = d\bar{q}(\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q}{R})$$
where $V$ is the electric potential at distance $R$ from the charge $q$ and $d\bar{q}$ is a small part of $-q$ which I am bringing in and spreading around the shell. I took $d \bar{q} = \frac{q}{4 \pi R^2} R^2\sin \theta d\theta  d \phi$ and therefore $$W = \int dW = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{q}{R} (\frac{q}{4 \pi}) \int^{2 \pi}_{0}\int^{\pi}_{0}\sin \theta d \theta d \phi = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q^2}{R}.$$

As I understand, the answer should be $\frac{1}{8 \pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q^2}{R}$ so I am going wrong somewhere...By the way this is not a homework problem, I am not a registered student, just trying to learn some physics. This is related to a problem from the book Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths, fourth edition. A hint as to how to fix would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgot that when you bring $dq$ in, some of the negative charges are already there and you need to take into account their potential as well, which is easy by shell theorem. So the correct work done should be
$$-\int_0^{-q}dq'\left(\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R}+\frac{q'}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R}\right)$$
$$=\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R}-\frac{q^2/2}{4\pi \epsilon R}=\frac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 R}$$

Comment: @AlphGo Thanks, so you are using the Shell Theorem to get the contribution from the charges which are already there: $W = \int^{-q}_{0}\frac{q'}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}dq' = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}[\frac{q^2}{2}] = \frac{q^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_0 }$. What is the general statement of the Shell Theorem that you are using? Do you maybe have a reference for notes regarding this?

Comment: I am bring in $dq'$ shell by shell each with uniform distribution. And the Shell Theorem states that for a uniform shell, the field outside it is as if the charges were all at the center and the field inside it is zero. For details please check wiki.